# RVM: Ruby version changes after 'cd <Rails project>'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debian, rvm

I've been using **rvm** for a few years and never encountered this problem.  Can someone help me understand what is happening immediately after login?
Debian 10
Rails 6.1.4.1

```
    $ruby -v

    ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux]

    $cd rails/nbdb

    $ruby -v

    ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
```

My Gemfile contains the line:
`ruby '3.0.0'`

My .bash_profile contains:

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a .ruby-version file in your rails project?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a `.ruby-version` in rails/nbdb? If so, move it elsewhere and you should be good.

Comment: There is!  I didn't know about this file.  Thank you.  So basically, it's no longer standard convention to specify the ruby version in the Gemfile?

Comment: There are many different ways to define the project's Ruby version in the past – some are tool-related like `rbenv-version`, `.rvm_version`, `.tool-versions`, community conventions like `.ruby-version` or introduced by a company and later adopted by the community like `Gemfile`. Because there are so many different ways most tools have fallbacks and will work most with some other conventions too. It probably depends on who you ask what is defined as the standard convention to specific the Ruby version in a project.